# How can I click on the 'underlined words' in the rules dialog box for Outlook 2007?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, microsoft-outlook-2007

I am trying to create a rule in Outlook 2007 in my Windows 7 (64 bit) machine. I am unable to click on the underlined word shown in the dialog box below. The problem is that either the dialog box is getting cut-off or the underlined word is not working as a hyperlink. Any ideas as to what I need to do?

[image]

PS: If someone can edit the qn to add the image that would be great!

Comment: Judging by the font that's showing on your screen grab, I think your fonts are corrupt, which may be causing other problems. I've seen this in Vista but I'm basing it on a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a guess. Hold down CTRL and click it. It's how links used to work (may still be that way) by default in Word.

Try rebooting your whole system. It looks like there is an glitch with the wizard. All you have to is click on a link normally and it will open up a little box at the bottom of that window.

#### Example:

[image: Example of what it should look like]

Comment: Does not seem to work.

Comment: The problem you are having is effecting others. However, I don't see a solution. Try uninstall or reinstall if the reboot don't work.

Comment: Reboot does not seem to work. How do you know this is a prevalent issue? My google search did not show anything.